# weird encode character in email

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, html-email, mustache

I have a mustache template parsed via ruby and then render it by marking it html_safe against email body but resultant HTML has some weird encode character embedded in it, for example

```
<body style=3D"min-width:640px;margin: 0 0 0 0;" bgcolor=3D"#f6f6f6" link==3D"#000000" vlink=3D"#000000" alink=3D"#000000" text=3D"#000000">
  <br />

  <table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" align=3D"center" 
cellpadding=3D"0" c=
ellspacing=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#f6f6f6">
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor=3D"#f6f6f6" style=3D"border-bottom: 0;">
        <table width=3D"640" style=3D"min-width:640px;" 
cellspacing=3D"0"=
 cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"center">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor=3D"#000000">
            <table width=3D"640" bgcolor=3D"#000000" cellspacing=3D"0=
" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"center">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width=3D"600" height=3D"10" bgcolor=3D"#000000"=
 style=3D"line-height:0px;font-size:0px;">
                    <div width=3D"1" height=3D"10" alt=3D"" style=3D"=
display:block; border:0;"></div>
```

Why these character remains even after marking string as html safe? Am I missing something.
Mustache template is regular HTML template with mustache syntax in it that are to be replaced dynamically

Comment: tadman's right. Check your template to see if its being sent as quoted printable and it should fix those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [`quoted-printable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) style where it's similar to how things are escaped in a URL. You're probably used to `%20` but here `=20` is the same thing.

Since `=` is part of the escaping, like in HTML `&` becomes `&amp;` and in a URL `%` becomes `%25`, `=` must be encoded as `=3D`.

HTML just so happens to use a *lot* of `=` characters so you'll see the `=3D` sigil all over.

Comment: Just a quick note: if want to say `http://...?q=lorem`, it will be `http://...?q=30lorem`. So, that will become wrong parameter.

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir `?q=l` becomes `?q=3Dl` but that's only invalid if used raw. If it's decoded it turns back into `?q=l`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that we are using raw encode value. I needed to say that :|

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir Not sure why you'd be using the raw encoded value. That only makes sense inside a quoted-printable context, not as a link you can exercise directly. The quoted-printable encoding will also randomly break lines, so you may get the link cut into two or more pieces which require reassembly via proper decoding.